# Unable to get the filecount or list from AWS S3 bucket using javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cypress

I am using Cypress test and one of the validation is to get the count of files in S3 bucket.
But I am not able to do get the count of files in S3 bucket.

Below is the Cypress code.

```
describe('Validate api field validation', () => {
  
  it('Verify objects land in correct AWS S3 bucket', () => {
    var date = new Date();
    var bucketDirectory = date.getUTCFullYear()
    var bucketLocation = Cypress.env('aws_bucketLocation')
    cy.log(bucketDirectory)
    try{
      var ss=getCountOfFiles(bucketLocation,bucketDirectory)
    }
    catch(err){
      cy.log(err)
    }
    cy.log(ss)
  })
}
```

And below is the function I am using to get the count of files in S3 bucket.

```
 const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const fs = require("fs");
  
  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: 'xxxxx',
    secretAccessKey: 'yyyyyyy',
    region: 'abide',
  });
const getCountOfFiles = async (bucketname, prefix) => {
    try {
      cy.log(bucketname)
      cy.log(prefix)
      const data = await s3.listObjectsV2({
        Bucket: bucketname,
        Prefix: prefix, // Limcits response to keys that begin with specified prefix
      }).promise().then(mydata => {
        return mydata;
      })
      cy.log('---------')
      if (data.$response.error) {
        throw new Error('Could not list files in S3: ${data.$response.error}');
      }
      return data;
    } catch {e} {
      cy.log(e.message)
      //throw new Error('Could not list files in S3: ${e.message}');
    }
  };
```

I am trying to print out as whats happening in the log but even I am not able to catch the exception. I am not sure where I am going wrong here.
All data are perfect. It is something I am doing silly.
The directory exists in AWS. Even if it does not exist or something is wrong in input data, why no exception is printed??
Can anyone please help me here. Is it a limitation of Cypress??

Comment: Can you add the log output you get? Also, `getCountOfFiles` is `async`, so it returns a promise

Comment: Thanks a lot JessefSpecialisterren. There is no output here. The cypress test is green which indicates all is good. S3 bucket name and prefix are printed and stops there.

Comment: I mean, console.log(ss) does not print anything. Just a blank

Comment: What console output do you get if you replace the `var ss` line with `getCountOfFiles(bucketLocation,bucketDirectory).then(data => console.log("Data: ", data))`

Comment: @JessefSpecialisterren - just an {}